# How to export to excel with data is itemLabel in h:selectOneMenu use primefaces

Tags: excel, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a column use h:selectOneMenu in p:dataTable

```
<p:dataTable var="unit" value="#{p_bean.lstLevel}" id="listLevel" editable="true"
                                 paginatorTemplate="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.paginatorTemplate']}" paginatorPosition="top"
                                 rowsPerPageTemplate="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.rowsPerPageTemplate']}"
                                 currentPageReportTemplate="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.currentPageReportTemplate']}"
                                 paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="true" emptyMessage="#{qlaBundle['dataTable.emptyMessage']}"
                                 style="#{empty p_bean.displayDataTable || p_bean.displayDataTable ? null : 'display:none;'}"
                                 rows="#{sessionScope['ss_pagesize']}" selection="#{p_bean.selectedLevel}"
                                 lazy="true" rowKey="#{unit.rowNum}">
......
<p:column headerText="#{tdBundle['Tdkt_Vote.awardMethodName.label']}" >
       <f:facet name="header">  
           <h:outputText value="#{tdBundle['Tdkt_Vote.awardMethodName.label']}" />  
       </f:facet>
       <h:selectOneMenu label="#{unit.awardMethodName}" value="#{unit.awardMethodId}">
          <f:selectItems value="#{p_bean.lstAwardMethod}" var="al"
             itemLabel="#{al.vnname}" itemValue="#{al.awardMethodId}"/>
           <p:ajax event="blur" immediate="true" partialSubmit="true" global="false"/>
       </h:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
.......
<p:commandLink title="Xuất excel" ajax="false">
      <p:graphicImage height="30" width="30" value="/resources/images/icon_excel.png"/>
      <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="listLevel" fileName="dataAll" postProcessor="#{tdktVoteCs.exportLeveltoExel}"/>
  </p:commandLink>
```

And My function in bean:

```
 public void exportLeveltoExel(Object document){
    HSSFWorkbook wb = (HSSFWorkbook) document;
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow header = sheet.getRow(0);  

    HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();    
    cellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(HSSFColor.AQUA.index);  
    cellStyle.setFillPattern(HSSFCellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);  

    for(int i=0; i < header.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();i++) {  
        HSSFCell cell = header.getCell(i);  

        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);  
    }  
}
```

When export to excel it show **itemValue** that column, but i want to show **itemLabel** of that column. How can i do that ?

Comment: I think in reality it is exporting `value="#{unit.awardMethodId}"`, that's probably why this is the value and not the label.

Comment: Yeap, I get *id* to process in code, display is *name*. And now i want display *name* in excel file, not *id*